# How to choose between HDMI and displayport sound output using radeon free drivers

Tags: sound, multiple-monitors, radeon, hdmi, displayport

My graphics card is a
    VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Turks XT [Radeon HD 6670/7670]

I'm using open source drivers and have 3 screens plugged in, using DVI, HDMI and DisplayPort.

I'd like to have to sound redirected to the DisplayPort-connected monitor instead of the HDMI-connected one.

In sound settings, I can choose between
1.Digital output (S/PDIF) (my motherboard's I guess), or
2.HDMI / DisplayPort - Turks/Whistler HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6000 Series], but despite the name, it uses HDMI output and not DisplayPort output.

Where do I set that ?

Answer (score 2):

Try using [Pulseaudio Volume Control](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pavucontrol/)

[image: pavucontrol]

<sub>My computer does not have a displayport, or DVI :-(</sub>

You just need to run `pavucontrol` in terminal after it is installed, and it offers more advanced settings to that of the normal sound settings.